# How to implement Maven Properties for an Application where repos are dependent on each other

Tags: java, maven, properties, snapshot

We are building one monolithic application. We have few repos to build which are depending on others. For example we have 3 repos named as
A, B and C.

B and C are dependent on A. And we should build A first then B and C. And the snapshot version also should be same for all the repos. We added properties
for a the snapshot version and try to build the repos Where A is built successfully and B is failed as B is not getting some dependencies from A.

We tried to pass Snapshot version as parameters using -DnewVersion=, -Drevision=2.0.0 etc commands.

But could not build 'B' successfully. Any help would be highly appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about using just one repo and construct a multi-module project?

Comment: Strongly recommend to go into a multi module project ...makes it easier to handle all the stuff..as already suggest by @JFabianMeier

Comment: @JFabianMeier Thanks for your swift response. Could you please elaborate more on the constructing multi-module project?

Comment: We do follow the multi-module architecture for our repositories. But How can we make it to use just one repo?